# Modifying URL date with Powershell

Tags: powershell

Attempting to download a .csv file from the net automatically each day.

I've so far setup a string $date, to use in the URL (if thats right).

Changed the TLS from 1.0 to 1.2

Make webrequest to the server, save output to file.

I just now need the $date to automatically change the URL.

Anyone know of an easy way to do this? Or do I completely need to redo the script?

Cheers,

```
$date = Get-Date
    [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 
[System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$params = @{
    'Uri'     = @"https://website.net/v1/exportstation=32&buffer=daily&type=data&fileType=csv&grap hType=degreeDays&$(
    'start={0:yyyy-MM-dd}&end={1:yyyy-MM-dd}' -f @($date.AddDays(-1), $date)
)&from=0|7&to=30|2&yearRanges=$($date.Year)
"@
    'OutFile' = "$Env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\File.csv"
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest using some form of string concatenation to make your script more readable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use string expands to call the `$date` in different formats. So below I call it 3 times, once to get yesterday's date `$($Date.AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd'))`, once to get today's date `$($Date.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd'))`, and finally to get yesterday's year `$($Date.AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyy'))`.

```
$date = Get-Date
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
Invoke-WebRequest ` 
    -Uri "https://website.net/v1/exportstation=32&buffer=daily&type=data&fileType=csv&graphType=degreeDays&start=$($Date.AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd'))&end=$($Date.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd'))&from=0|7&to=30|2&yearRanges=$($Date.AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyy'))" `
    -Outfile C:\USERS\PC\DESKTOP\FILE.CSV
```

I think this should be able to get a report of yesterday if I understood what your Uri meant.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use a combination of

- [string format operator](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html)
- [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-5.1)

---

```
## Q:\Test\2018\10\19\SO_52891734.ps1
$Date  = (Get-Date).Date
$Start = "&start={0:yyyy-MM-dd}" -f $Date.AddDays(-1)
$End   = "&end={0:yyyy-MM-dd}"   -f $Date
$Year  = "&yearRanges={0:yyyy}"  -f $Date.AddDays(-1)
$Other = "&buffer=daily&type=data&fileType=csv&graphType=degreeDays&from=0|7&to=30|2"

$params = @{
    Uri     = "https://website.net/v1/exportstation=32$Other$Start$End$Year" 
    OutFile = "C:\USERS\PC\DESKTOP\FILE.CSV"
}

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

Invoke-WebRequest @params
```

Comment: You should only need to get the date once, and in your `$Year` example, you can simplify it to `{0}`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 If I store the date in a sep. var, yes. **DONE**

Answer (score 0):

To complement the other answers and to promote a more readable solution, here is the method I would use to tackle this problem to dynamically add the date to the URL:

```
$date = Get-Date
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol =
    [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$params = @{
    'Uri'     = @"
https://website.net/v1/exportstation=32&buffer=daily&type=data&fileType=csv&graphType=degreeDays&$(
    'start={0:yyyy-MM-dd}&end={1:yyyy-MM-dd}' -f @($date.AddDays(-1), $date)
)&from=0|7&to=30|2&yearRanges=$($date.Year)
"@
    'OutFile' = "$Env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\File.csv"
}
Invoke-WebRequest @params
```

It is not wise to only support one protocol, so I use the bitwise-or to add TLS1.2 into the support stack.

Comment: This works great for me. I can understand only a little bit of it though (never coded before yesterday). Could you please explain it a bit?

Comment: Is it possible to edit the OutFile to reflect certain variables? Ideally, I'd like the "File.csv" to be called "Station#date.csv".

Comment: @Marshy I would recommend reading this article [about_Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-5.1) for explanation about the `$params` hashtable I define and `@params` syntax.  [about_Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-5.1) explains the `-f` (format) operator.

Comment: @Marshy Yes, you can change the outfile to use a variable or use a different name of your choosing.  I'm not 100% if `#` is a valid windows path character.

Comment: 'OutFile' = "$Env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\Station32 $(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).csv" is what I used for changing OutFile to have current date on it.